# Scroll in VS Code on first Page Down key-press when cursor is on first line

Tags: visual-studio-code

When the cursor is at the top of the editor window, if I press Page Down, VS Code only moves the cursor to the last line in the window. It needs a second Page Down key-press to actually scroll to the next page.

Can I configure VS Code to scroll on the first key-press so it works like less, nano, vim, emacs and others ? The only editor I remember that scrolls like VS Code is Programmer's Notepad.

Using VS Code 1.69 freshly installed on Ubuntu-20.04, with C++ extension from Microsoft while editing a .cpp file.

Comment: Notepad and VSC are both from Microsoft

Answer (score 0):

Create a keybinding for `pageDown` with a `when` context test on line number using [Extra Context](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.extra-context) v0.3.0 and context variable `extraContext:editorSelectionStartLineRelativeVisibleTop` and extension [multi-command](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ryuta46.multi-command)

```
  {
    "key": "pagedown",
    "command": "extension.multiCommand.execute",
    "when": "textInputFocus && extraContext:editorSelectionStartVisible && extraContext:editorSelectionStartLineRelativeVisibleTop < 3",
    "args": {
        "sequence": [
            "cursorPageDown",
            "cursorPageDown",
            "cursorPageUp"
        ]
    }
  }
```

There is a [bug in VSC](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/157194) that does not make this keybinding work every time. Until it is fixed you can see the effect by first using `ArrowLeft` or `ArrowRight` before pressing `PageDown`.

---

**Edit**

It was not a bug in VSC but used the Visible Range at the wrong time.

Selection and Visible Range update at different times.

Extension v0.4.1 fixes the behavior.

Added a `cursorPageUp` to the key binding to keep cursor at the top of the screen.

Comment: editorSelectionStartLine==1 sounds like the first line in the file but this "no scroll" happens if cursor is at the top of the window (viewport), not top of the file.

Comment: @patraulea I have updated the extension and the answer but VSC has a small bug (see edits)

Comment: Thanks. I installed multi-command and Extra Context, and the new cursorPageDown command runs. But it moves the cursor two pages down with one pagedown keypress whereas other editors scroll by one page, and move the cursor by just one page as well.

Comment: @patraulea Then add a `cursorPageUp` command

Comment: @patraulea Fixed the extension, if it works for you you can accept the answer